# Does singularity support the gpu resources framework capability?

Tags: gpu, mesos, hubspot

I'm trying to use singularity to schedule tasks that use cuda over a mesos cluster. Mesos slaves do seem to support gpu resources that frameworks can make use of, but it seems the frameworks need to be flagged as gpu consumers.

Is this an option that is supported by singularity ? And if not, is there an alternative mesos framework that is gpu aware and can launch tasks other than long running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now Singularity does not support for gpu resources.

Only 3 frameworks support gpu resources:

1. **Marathon** (services)
2. **Aurora** (batch jobs, services, etc)
3. **Spark** (Map/Reduce jobs)

**Chronos** has just been reborn. Supporting gpu resources will be added soon.
**Metronome** (there is the unofficial docker image) will support gpu resources soon as well.

Comment: Ticket related to this for Singularity https://github.com/HubSpot/Singularity/issues/1346